# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, hyperlink, http-headers, anchor

On a custom wordpress page I click on my links and I get this error
Also the links don't open. Clicking doesn't do anything.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load mysite/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'mysite' is therefore not allowed access.

Where mysite is the url of my website.

Is anyone familiar with this issue?

The page where the error occurs is: http://wouterleduc.com/publications/

And I'm using this code on my page template:
`

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <h3 class="h3_serie_overzicht"><?php the_title(); ?><span id="<?php the_title();?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><a href"#" class="serie_overzicht_info" id="<?php the_title(); ?>">Show text</a></h3>

    <div class="serie_overzicht_info_pane"><?php echo the_content(); ?></div>

<div id="serie-overzicht-thumbs">
    <?php $attachments = new Attachments( 'attachments' ); ?>
    <?php if( $attachments->exist() ) : ?>
      <div class="serie_overzicht_row">
        <?php while( $attachments->get() ) : ?>
          <div class="serie_foto">
           <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $attachments->field( 'link' ); ?>" title="<?php echo $attachments->field( 'title' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $attachments->src( 'medium' ); ?>"" title="<?php echo $attachments->field( 'title' ); ?>" alt="<?php echo $attachments->field( 'title' ); ?>" /><br /><span><?php echo $attachments->field( 'title' ); ?></span></a>
          </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

`

I use the attachments pluging from Jonathan Christopher to display images. I use fancybox in my theme but it should only effect the links with a rel tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are missing the cross-origin request header. I checked as follows

```
curl -I http://wouterleduc.com/publications/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 19:40:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.32
X-Pingback: http://wouterleduc.com/xmlrpc.php
Link: <http://wouterleduc.com/?p=2358>; rel=shortlink
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Add the following line to your php code

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://mysite");
?>
```

You can use curl to test it. If all is well then your XmlHttpRequest should work. There are some security implications. I would have a look at http://enable-cors.org to find out more.

Comment: Hey Snow6boy, thanks for answering. I have added the php code you suggested in my index.php which is the file that assembles all the needed code for wordpress but this still seems to trigger the same error.
What i'm confused about is that i'm not trying to do something difficult here. Just outputting an anchor tag. plain html.
Therefore I think the problem is with a script or something but I'm stuck on what is causing it